# MEAN Stack Get Username from UserId forEach row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I'm trying to get the user data (such as username) for each user on a row of reviews. I kept my user information (login credentials on another model/controller), so is there a way to access and show the username on the view?

Below is my JSON code:

```
{
   "_id": "56873fc9182b3741059357d0",
   "longitude": 113.83507800000007,
   "latitude": 22.1533884,
   "location": "Hong Kong",
   "name": "Hong Kong",
   "__v": 0,
   "category": "Attraction",
   "reviews": [
   {
      "comment": "Add the comment to the form",
        "rating": 3.5,
        "userId": 11,
        "review_id": "44NL7kkwhy72"
    },
    {
       "comment": "Hello test",
       "rating": "3.4",
        "userId": "56809c0cf0a264b101a1dd61",
        "review_id": "jN7f1iFlQVha"
      },
      {
        "comment": "Hello test ty",
        "rating": "3.7",
        "userId": "56863c8f2959b4c601fbd9eb",
        "review_id": "QcJpw4yopF1q"
      }
   ]
  },
```

//view all reviews for a location

```
    .controller('AllReviews', function($scope, $stateParams, LocFac, UserFac) {   

    id = $stateParams.id;  

    LocFac.getLocation(id).then(function(data) { 
       $scope.locations = data.data; 
       $scope.reviews = data.data.reviews;  

      //variables to show information on location reviews
       $scope.lengthrev = (data.data.reviews).length; 
       $scope.locationname = data.data.name; 

       //addition of values and retrieve the value
        $scope.getTotal = function(){
         var total = 0;
         for(var i = 0; i < $scope.lengthrev; i++){
          var review = $scope.reviews[i];

          User.getUser(review).then(function(datat) { 
             $scope.locun = datat.username; 
          }); 

         total += review.rating; 
        }
        return total;
       }

      grandtotal = $scope.getTotal(); 

      //get average of all values \
      $scope.averagereviews = grandtotal/($scope.lengthrev); 
   }); 
})
```

My location reviews view

```
<ion-view view-title="All Reviews" class="all_reviews">
 <ion-content class="all_reviews"> 

<h3>{{ locationname }}</h3>  

<h3>Average Rating: {{ averagereviews }} <ng-rate-it name="rating" ng-model="averagereviews" resetable="false" read-only="true"></ng-rate-it>/ {{ lengthrev }} Reviews </h3> 

<ion-list>
  <ion-item data-ng-repeat="location in locations.reviews"> 
        <ng-rate-it name="rating" ng-model="location.rating" resetable="false" read-only="true"></ng-rate-it>  
       {{ location.userId }}
       <h4>{{ location.review_id }}</h4>  
       <h4>{{ location.comment }}</h4>
  </ion-item> 
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Isn't it working for `{{ review.userId }} `?

Comment: You want to access the logged in user's details?

Comment: @Raghu, I'd like to show the author of each review based on the userId

Comment: But where is users info? It's necessary to ask API for that, right?

Comment: @JeffreyTeruel Can you create an api that can return the username if user id is passed? Then you can pass `review.userId` as input and get the username.
If you already have the all the user information,then move it to a service instead of model/controller.So that you can expose the information through the service.

Comment: @Raghu, for my node application, my API to get the user details as you requested is under UserFac.getUser(userid).success(function(data));

Comment: @JeffreyTeruel I have updated an answer using the `UserFac` service.Try that code snippet and check whether it satisfy your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your two aysnc operations,(one to fetch reviews and another one to fetch usernames) I think this approach will be more suitable.

1. First fetch the reviews.
2. Display the reviews.
3. While displaying the reviews use the UserFac to fetch the username asynchronously using `ng-init` directive.

I have created a demo plunker as an example with the sample data you provided in question.

**Example:**

[Demo Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/7RrnpAOJz3OpPeNwe8j8)

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.factory('LocFac', function($http) {
  var factory = {};

  factory.getLocation = function(id) {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'data.json'
    });
  }

  return factory;
});
app.factory('UserFac', function($http) {
  var factory = {};

  factory.getUser = function(id) {
    return $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'user.json'
    });
  }

  return factory;
});
app.controller('AllReviews', function($scope, LocFac, UserFac) {
  $scope.show = false;
  $scope.testClick = function() {
    id = "56873fc9182b3741059357d0";
    LocFac.getLocation(id).then(function(data) {
      $scope.reviews = data.data.reviews;
      $scope.lengthrev = (data.data.reviews).length;
      $scope.show = true;
    });
  }

  $scope.getUserName=function(review) {
    UserFac.getUser(review.id).then(function(user) {
     review.userName=user.data.userName;
     review.showUserName=true;
    });
  }
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AllReviews">
    <button ng-click="testClick()">Click here</button>
    <ul ng-show="show" ng-repeat="review in reviews track by $index" ng-init="getUserName(review)">
      {{review | json : spacing}}
      <p ng-show="review.showUserName">
        {{review.userName}}
      </p>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Explanation:**

While iterating the review array in `ng-repeat`,we pass the review object to the UserFac service to fetch the userName.This service will set the name inside the review object itself.

Comment: @JeffreyTeruel Sorry for the late reply. I have updated my answer and a demo plunker that I hope matches your usage scenario.